# Slick carousel individual overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Explanation

I'm trying to set a overlay on each image of the slider ([slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)) when hovering them, but for some reason, when I hover it, the overlay appears on top of the slider (all 12 images), not the image hovered.

### Code

You can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thffcgqc/) and in ["fullscreen mode"](http://jsfiddle.net/thffcgqc/embedded/result/).

ps: it's be better to see the overlay content in fullscreen.

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    rows: 3
});
```

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    position: relative;
}

img {
    background-color: black;
}

.slick-slide {
    text-align: center !important;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(1, 1, 1, .35);
    transition: 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-content {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <section class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <ul class="col-md-12 carousel text-center">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="overlay-content">
                                    <h4>content</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why is it not working?

Your code doesn't work as expected because your overlay is being positioned relatively to `.carousel-wrapper` not the `a` element (`.carousel-wrapper` is the first parent of `.overlay` that has `position` other than `static` - if you don't set your `position` explicitly it defaults to `static`).

### How to avoid this mistake in the future?

If you want any element on your website to have an overlay (or in general you want to use `position: absolute` somewhere) you need to remember that this element is going to be positioned relatively to it's parent that has `positon: relative` or `position: absolute`. If there's no such element it's going to position itself to `<html>`.

It's very well explained here:

> Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element
>   with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent,
>   it will default all the way back up to the  element itself
>   meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.

(on absolute positioning)

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

### Check the working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/thffcgqc/2/

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks you!! It worked perfectly and your answer is just awesome. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your anchor tags and overlay content in a separate div and style as follows. The reason is due to the fact that you are not using a margin-right for whitespace between boxes. You are simply using a fixed with `li` tags and the images leaves a gap in the parent container . If an overlay is placed, you will see the overlay over the white gap and the image (which is somewhat not what you want - I believe)

See snippet below

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  slidesPerRow: 3,
  rows: 3
});
```

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
  position: relative;
}

img {
  background-color: black;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, .35);
  transition: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay-content {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1
}

.img_cont {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <section class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <ul class="col-md-12 carousel text-center">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <div class="img_cont">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onedlq.com/wp-content/themes/komodo/img/no-image-140.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overlay-content">
                    <h4>content</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked perfectly. I'm accepting Bart's answer because he answered before, but your answer is just as great as his.

Comment: Welcome. have a great day :D